# Copy a column to another row that has duplicate value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this.

```
ID   Name    Country  Published
1    Madrid           0
2    Madrid  Spain    1
3    Paris   France   0
4    London  England  0
```

In any case where the name is the same, I need to copy the Country from the Published=1 entry to the Published=0 entry. I've been doing it by hand like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET Country=(SELECT Country FROM mytable  WHERE ID = 2) WHERE ID=1
```

but is there any way to do this automatically instead of going through every single entry by hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do it with join:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      Name VARCHAR(20) ,
      Country VARCHAR(20) ,
      Published BIT
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 'Madrid', NULL, 0 ),
        ( 2, 'Madrid', 'Spain', 1 ),
        ( 3, 'Paris', 'France', 0 ),
        ( 4, 'London', 'England', 0 )


UPDATE t1 SET Country = t2.Country
FROM @t t1
JOIN @t t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND t2.Published = 1
WHERE t1.Country IS NULL AND t1.Published = 0

SELECT * FROM @t
```

Output:

```
ID  Name    Country Published
1   Madrid  Spain   0
2   Madrid  Spain   1
3   Paris   France  0
4   London  England 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable SET Country= a.Country from 
(SELECT Country,id FROM mytable  WHERE Published = 1) a
WHERE Published=0 and a.name=mytable.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Hope it will help you

```
update t1
    set t1.country = t2.country
    from table t1
    inner join table t2
    on t1.Name = t2.Name and t2.published = 1
    where t1.published = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query you just need to change the `ID` reference to match the correlated sub-query based on `Name` and add filters for `Published` and `Country`

```
UPDATE t
SET Country = (SELECT TOP 1 Country FROM t t2 WHERE t2.Name = t.Name AND Published = 1 ORDER BY Country)
WHERE Published = 0
AND Country IS NULL;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5de49/1)